# How can I detect a non-menu page in NavEE?

Tags: navee

I'm working on a site with hundreds of imported pages. Many of them won't be in a menu and are findable by using site search. We have a contextual sidebar menu in the left column and when these non-assigned pages are viewed, the left column is empty.

I'd like to add a default menu (and breadcrumbs) for any un-assigned page. Is there a way to detect if a page isn't in a menu and use a conditional to load a default if no match is found?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think if there is such a tag in NavEE so that you can check that current page is from the navigation of NavEE module. But you can try SQL with query module like:

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_navs FROM exp_navee WHERE link LIKE '%{current_path}%'"}

{if total_navs == 0}

###### 
code
######

{/if}

{/exp:query}
```

{current_path} is standard global variable (http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/single_variables.html#current-path)

I hope, it would work for you.